# Pyright strict type-checking mode won't work in Sublime Text 4.0

Tags: python, types, pyright

I have installed LSP and LSP-pyright in Sublime Text 4 and included `"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict"` within the `LSP-pyright.sublime-settings` file but `Pyright` still won't raise any Type error when I wrote the following code:

```py
def foo(x, y):
    return x + y
```

To add, it seems the basic type-checking mode still work since the code

```py
import unknownpackage
```

makes Pyright raise `reportMissingImports`. So what seems to be the problem?